# How to handle an incorrect POST request using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, url, post, routes

**TL;DR**
**Form submits a POST request with "data/fileUpload".**
**Server responds 200 and renders a new page. Goody.**

**Try to upload a new file in the rendered page again.**
**POST request is now "data/fileUpload/fileUpload".**
**Server doesn't know what to do. Baddy.**

I am not exactly sure what is going on, that's why the title is very vague. I am implementing a simple feature to a Node (Express) application.
Here is what this feature does:

- User uploads a file.
- User submits the file for review.
- User receives a response.

**Problem**

Uploading a file and returning a result functionality works smoothly. After file is uploaded and the server renders a new page, browser is still at "data/fileUpload" url. Trying to upload a second file directs a POST request to the following url "data/fileUpload/fileUpload" which can not be routed by the server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Boilerplate ... -->
    <body
    <div id="form">
         <%= message %>
         <% if(processed == "true"){ %>
         <%= results %>
         <% }; %>
         <form method='post' action='data/fileUpload' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type='file' name='fileUploaded' id="browseButton" required>
            <input type='submit' value="Upload" id="uploadButton">
      </div>
     <script>
        var uploadField = document.getElementById("browseButton");
        uploadField.onchange = function() {
            if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
            alert("File is too big!");
            this.value = "";
            };
        };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the form action is "data/fileUpload". This post request is handled by the following router and controllers.

```js
// Defined in app.js
app.use('/data',  dataRouter);
```

The following Router is in data.js. processController is imported from processData.js controller.

```js
router.post('/fileUpload', [processController.fileUpload, processController.process]);
```

And this is the Controller for fileUpload and process.

```js
exports.fileUpload = function(req, res,next) {
   // Upload the file... 
   next(); // calls process function
};

// Process the data. Not implemented
exports.process = function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {processed:"true", 
            message: "hello", results:"result" });
    });
};
```

The following is the incomplete directory tree.

├── app.js
├── controllers
│   └── processController.js
├── package.json
├── routes
│   ├── data.js
├── uploads
│   └── Uploaded.file
└── views
    ├── index.ejs

How can I enable server to go back to the initial page but also send results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `res.redirect()` combined with [`req.flash() - connect flash (that at some point got excluded from expressjs bundle)`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#readme) for what you are trying to do. (Which is sending an ok/not-ok message back to front).

`res.render()` Sends back an html (or any other engine) template back to front and renders - It does not care for what happens next and this can cause problems such as yours (sending a full page as template and messing up data).

`res.redirect()` redirects the user to another route (by this restarting the request like: `GET /some_new_or_even_the_same_route`.

`req.flash()` Can handle returned messages.

Also, with `redirect()` you could send a status code as the first argument which can act as your `processed true/false`

I think `res.render()` is just not the right function to use in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you! I found another way to fix this problem by changing the form action to an absolute url : "localhost:3000/data/fileUpload". Obviously localhost needs to change once in production.

Comment: @a_a_a Sure thing!
 take in mind that `Absolute URLs contain more information than relative urls, as they also include the protocol (e.g http://) and the domain name.` 
`protocol://domain/path` - Your syntax assumes a protocol so it's not absolute yet. this will require your further attention - There are pros and cons for absolute/relative paths. [further reading](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp), [more reading](https://clever-solution.com/blog/absolute-vs-relative-urls)