# so i have an issue, on clicking register the server loads user/user/register....what might be the problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, agents-jade

these are the node.js codes in my project
i used jade so the register and login are the templates in my view folder
this is the app.js code

```
 var router = express.Router();
 var multer = require('multer');
 var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{title:'Register'});
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{title:'Login'});
});

router.post('/register', upload.single('profilepicture'), function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;
  
  if(req.file){
    console.log('uploading..');
  }
  else{
    console.log('not uploading');
  }
  //form validator
  req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('username','Username required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password','Password cannot be empty').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
  //check errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log('no errors');
  }
});



module.exports = router;
```

on clicking register the server adds another /users to the url

error being displayed
[this is the error being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIVgF.png)

Comment: try setting an absolute URL in the form action or using `res.redirect()` instead of `render()` [maybe this post can explain the differences between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62751282/1283672)

Comment: Please add error description instead of pic

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there was a slashback left out on the jade template i.e.
`form(method='post' action='/users/register' enctype='multipart/form-data')`  I've done this for possible future devs who might encounter this issue